# How to make a file in Excel, that refreshes from Query Editor and work on it

Tags: excel, office365, powerquery

I am using Power Query Editor to create a working file, using multiple tables from several sources.

After I combine these and make my working file, I am using it to make some work on columns I add later on the working file.

I have noticed that the values I enter in the working file are not bound to the main key, lets assume the first column, but they are independent values in a column.

The result is that if one table changes, for example one line is deleted or I change the sorting of the Query, my working file is wrong, since the data changed but the added columns remain as they were.

Is there a way to have the added columns to be bound with a value, as it is for example with VLOOKUP?

How can I make a file that will update from different sourcesbut stil I can work on it without the risk of misplacing the work I do.

I hope I am clear.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: MS Query? or PowerQuery? MS Query is ancient, and I wouldn't recommend anyone use it, now that PowerQuery is on the scene.

Comment: My apologies. PowerQuery i was using

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple *if* each line in your table is unique (which in your example you say the first column can serve as a key). Setup your working columns on the table and then load the table into PQ (as a connection only). Then go to your original query that is combining your data and add a merge at the end where you merge against the table you just loaded into PQ and match on your key. Then expand only your working columns from the merge.

This way whenever you refresh your table, it will match lines against it's existing output in your work before updating, so data in your work columns will be maintained. However note this is only going to retain *values*, not any formulas you may be using in your work columns.